# Flutter Pub error -- Because no versions of logger match 1.1.0 and no versions of logger match >1.1.0 <2.0.0, logger ^1.1.0 is forbidden

Tags: flutter, dart, logging, version, pubspec

I'm using Ubuntu and I'm constantly getting this project and can resolve it.

I have successfully **Flutter doctor -v** and everything is ok!

But the problem never stops

error
Because no versions of logger match 1.1.0 and no versions of logger match >1.1.0 <2.0.0, logger ^1.1.0 is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of version conflict.... it comes if you use any older version of particular dependency or one dependency not compatible with another...you can try to remove older version and update it with latest version.

Then the issue will fix